# Why won't my div expand vertically?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an enrolment form for a training company which works on a jQuery slider. The content on the last page (a summary page) changes dynamically depending on the user inputs. For some reason, the container div will not expand vertically if the content on the last page exceeds the size of the container.

The overflow is set to hidden to hide the horizontal parts of the slider. Is there a way I can get the container to expand if the content pushes below the bottom boundaries?

The form can be found at http://testing.xenongroupadmin.com/enrolment/

To properly see the effect I am talking about, try entering a really really long address into the 'Home Address' and 'Work Address' inputs.

Any help on this would be really useful!

Thanks!

Comment: Da code, man, we need da code!!!

Comment: Can we see the code? What have you tried before?

Comment: Hi there, you should be able to see the code if you follow the link and view source/inspect elements - let me know if this isn't enough and I'll add the code in. Problem is it's a huge document and didn't want to paste the whole thing in this one post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've found the problem - I didn't notice that one of the container divs inside the form had a fixed height, so wasn't expanding when the content expanded.

Thanks for taking a look though!

Chris